# Python IF statements with common ELSE

Tags: python, validation, if-statement

I'm trying to validate user input, however my problem is that with the current code if the first `IF` statement is true then the rest of the `ELIF` statements will not be sought through. This means that if there is an error in the first entry box the rest of the entry boxes do not get validated, this is my code:

```
            if (len(MemberID)) > 4:
                  self.MemberIDError.configure(fg = "red") 
            elif (len(Postcode)) > 7:
                  self.PostcodeError.configure(fg = "red")                      
            elif (len(Age)) > 3:
                  self.AgeError.configure(fg = "red")
            elif (len(Mass)) > 3:
                  self.MassError.configure(fg = "red")                        
            elif (Name == '') or (MemberID == '') or (Postcode == '') or (Age == '') or (Gender == '') or (Mass == ''):
                self.CreateError.configure(fg = "red")
                conn.commit()
            else:
                List = [Name, MemberID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Mass]
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO memb(Name, MemberID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Mass) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",(Name, MemberID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Mass))
                conn.commit()
```

Alternatively, if I change the "ELIF" statements to "IF" statements, wrong user input will still be added to the database. What can I do to ensure the user input is properly validated, and why are the "ELIF" statements not being used.

Comment: There is a difference between `if` and `elif`.

Comment: Why do you use `elif` then? Instead of a second `if`, etc?

Comment: write multiple `if` statements instead of `elif`.

Comment: Can all of the answers here please the indentation mistake in the question.

Comment: Use an if statement for each one. If you have a program where multiple conditions can be True, you always want to use if statements so that each condition is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Just put multiple `IF` statements, and keep track of whether or not it's valid:

```
        valid=True

        if (len(MemberID)) > 4:
              self.MemberIDError.configure(fg = "red")
              valid=False 
        if (len(Postcode)) > 7:
              self.PostcodeError.configure(fg = "red") 
              valid=False                     
        if (len(Age)) > 3:
              self.AgeError.configure(fg = "red")
              valid=False
        if (len(Mass)) > 3:
              self.MassError.configure(fg = "red")
              valid=False                        
        if (Name == '') or (MemberID == '') or (Postcode == '') or (Age == '') or (Gender == '') or (Mass == ''):
              valid=False
            self.CreateError.configure(fg = "red")
            conn.commit()
        if valid:
            List = [Name, MemberID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Mass]
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO memb(Name, MemberID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Mass) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",(Name, MemberID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Mass))
            conn.commit()
```

Comment: The problem with this however is that if one of the limits is exceeded as long as there are no null values it will still be inserted into the database.

Comment: @NaracSnave We do not know the logic you are trying to work out with the `if` statements but the point to Artemis answer is you may use multiple if statements.

Comment: @NaracSnave I have edited it to keep track of validity.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing `if` statements with `elif` statements what you are doing is telling the program to check the first `if` statement and if valid then do not check other `elif` statements below. This will check in order until one of the `if/elif` is valid or until you run out of `if/elif` statements.

What you want to do if you wish to have each parameter checked regardless of if the previous `if` statement works or not then you need to write it as multiple if statements.

Something like this:

```
if (len(MemberID)) > 4:
    self.MemberIDError.configure(fg = "red") 
if (len(Postcode)) > 7:
    self.PostcodeError.configure(fg = "red")                      
if (len(Age)) > 3:
    self.AgeError.configure(fg = "red")
if (len(Mass)) > 3:
    self.MassError.configure(fg = "red")                        
if (Name == '') or (MemberID == '') or (Postcode == '') or (Age == '') or (Gender == '') or (Mass == ''):
    self.CreateError.configure(fg = "red")
    conn.commit()
if:
    List = [Name, MemberID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Mass]
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO memb(Name, MemberID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Mass) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",(Name, MemberID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Mass))
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is elif basically says if the previous if doesnt work, and it meets this second condition, but since the previous condition did work it never activates the second comparison. This should work:

```
x = 0
y = 0
While x == 0:

    if (len(MemberID)) > 4:
        self.MemberIDError.configure(fg = "red")
        y = 1
    if (len(Postcode)) > 7:
        self.PostcodeError.configure(fg = "red")
        y = 1
    if (len(Age)) > 3:
        self.AgeError.configure(fg = "red")
        y = 1
    if (len(Mass)) > 3:
        self.MassError.configure(fg = "red") 
        y = 1
    if (Name == '') or (MemberID == '') or (Postcode == '') or (Age == '') or (Gender == '') or (Mass == ''):
        self.CreateError.configure(fg = "red")
        conn.commit()
        y = 1

    if y != 0:
        print "Fix changes in red"
        break
    else:
        List = [Name, MemberID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Mass]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO memb(Name, MemberID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Mass) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",(Name, MemberID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Mass))
        conn.commit()
        break
```

[EDIT] So I think I see what you're trying to do. You're attempting input validation. What I've done is I've looped everything. If theres an error, I'm setting the value of a new variable "y" to 1, the code will continue to go through and check everything, but when it gets to the bottom, even if one thing is input incorrectly, it will tell you to fix things in red, and break the loop. Alternatively if nothing is broken it adds the member to the database.

Comment: The problem with this however is that if one of the limits is exceeded as long as there are no null values it will still be inserted into the database.

Comment: Ok edited it, check it now and let me know if this is what you are looking for